# Show every item in a DynamoDB database in a Flutter app (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have a Flutter app which is written in Dart that will become an Android and iOS app. I have a table in a DynamoDB on AWS that I want to show every entry in that table in the Flutter app. It will only be 5 or 10 items in the table as this is a demo for school, not a real app for a business. I have to use AWS and DynamoDB. I have used API Gateway to read an item using the primary key, but I want to show multiple items.

Through my research I am aware of using Lambda to scan the DynamoDB table and then using the API Gateway to connect to the Lambda.

Can anyone help?

I have located a few tutorials and pages about Lambda and querying a DynamoDB, but its unclear how that would make an API Gateway create a http endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be brief, as it's relatively straight forward, especially as you were already using `GetItem`. There are two ways to achieve it, one directly from API Gateway to DynamoDB, which I would advise against for you as VTL templates used for this are quite cumbersome.

The alternative is to use Lambda as a proxy to talk to DynamoDB. You then call DynamoDB `Scan` API to return all the data in the table:

1. [Set up Lambda proxy integrations in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html)
2. [Scan your items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)

Comment: When I return all data in Lambda, how would I read that data in Flutter/Dart?

Comment: API Gateway will invoke the Lambda and wait for a response. Lambda will invoke DynamoDB and wait for a response. The response from DynamoDB will go back to Lambda, and then from Lambda back to API Gateway and from there back to your application.

Comment: "Set up Lambda proxy integrations in API Gateway". I cannot understand the page you've linked it. What do I actually need to do in the API gateway for my case specifically?

Comment: Create a resource and method that proxies requests to Lambda.